# not centred concentric circles plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have spent sometimes doing this but I could not reach the solution. I have this code to plot concentric circles over 25 by 25 grids using ggplot2 in R. I do not know how to be able to manipulate the center of the concentric circles to be not at the origin(0,0), but at the center of the grid (5,5). I also would like to keep the scale of the grid from 25 to 25. Thank you very much in advance

```
 require(ggplot2)
 require(grid)

 x <- rep(seq(25), 25)
 y <- rep(seq(25), each=25)
 circ_rads <- seq(1,5,2)

qplot(x, y) +
  lapply(circ_rads, FUN = function(x)
      annotation_custom(circleGrob(gp = gpar(fill = "transparent", color = "black")), 
                        -x, x, -x, x)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = circ_rads + 0.1, label = circ_rads)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

[image: The output plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ggforce::geom_circle` like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

x <- rep(seq(25), 25)
y <- rep(seq(25), each=25)
circ_rads <- seq(1,5,2)

xy <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)

circles <- data.frame(
  x0 = 5, # You say circles should be a 'centre of the grid' and 5, 5
  y0 = 5, # not sure what you really mean, so going with 5, 5 here
  r = circ_rads
)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = xy, 
             aes(x, 
                 y)) +
  geom_circle(data = circles, 
              aes(x0 = x0,
                  y0 = y0,
                   r = r)) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. That is exactly what I have been trying to  figure out.  Thank you again.

Comment: No worries at all. If this answered your question, you should [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/181565) to indicate that to others